# The pipe ' ' could not be found - error after Angular upgrade

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to upgrade Angular 4 to latest (7.0.3), everything was well until production compilation. In it I received:

```
ERROR in : Template parse errors:
The pipe 'filter' could not be found ("v class="form-group">
    <ul class="ui-select-list">
      <li [attr.name]="item.id" *ngFor="let [ERROR ->]item of data | filter : qModel" innerHtml="{{ 'AAA' | translate }}"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
"): C:/x/src/app/components/ui/fields/combo/ui.combo.html@2:44
The pipe 'translate' could not be found ("s="ui-select-list">
      <li [attr.name]="item.id" *ngFor="let item of data | filter : qModel" inn[ERROR ->]erHtml="{{ 'AAA' | translate }}"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
"): C:/x/src/app/components/ui/fields/combo/ui.combo.html@2:79
```

To reproduce the error I created a minimal repository from my code: https://github.com/ptrstpp950/myBugInAngular

Results are the following:

- `ng build --prod app` produces above error
- `ng build app` works 100% fine

I try to read about pipes in shared modules, I tried to make changes according to guides but still, without success.

Comment: are you using the pipe in more than one module?

Comment: In the example - no. In full app - yes.

Comment: I tried importing your GitHub repo on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/ptrstpp950/myBugInAngular), but it doesn't open.

Comment: @SiddAjmera it is compilation problem. I don't know which command StackBlitz uses

Comment: @PiotrStapp check my answer, it might be an issue with Ivy renderer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

from your tsconfig.json it seems you are using Ivy renderer in your Angular 7 project

as below -

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true
  }
```

you can make it `"enableIvy": false` and try the production build again.

During the production build (`ng build --prod`) it removes the pipes due to tree shaking. Ivy is not fully compatible yet and it can only be used for testing purpose . Before using Ivy you need to run `ngcc` to convert pre-Ivy packages to include Ivy definitions, `ngcc` is a command line tool from `@angular/compiler-cli` .

Please refer to the below links regarding Ivy renderer

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/core/src/render3/STATUS.md#implementation-status

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26436

Comment: I shouldn't write "thank you" in comments, but I'm soooo happy. It is working now. If I ever meet you in real I owe you a beer or something!

Comment: @PiotrStapp you are welcome :) .. I wish this will help others too

Comment: @Niladri I read this fix is for angular version below 8, but I am using angular 8.3 and getting this async error, I tried your solution but somehow getting different errors which are irreverent to pipe. Please adivse

Comment: @Niladri Same "ERROR Error: The pipe 'paginate' could not be found!"
"ERROR Error: The pipe 'async' could not be found!" after adding ivy as false,its giving error to some of my modules not found though I have added them into my appmodule

Comment: @Monica You can try to post your code as a separate question and link to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**You can make a [Shared module](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules) and export all your pipes from that shared module if you are using it in more than one module.**

---

For example just create a shared module like the follows:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { SearchFilterPipe } from './search-qafilter.pipe';
import { CapitalizePipe } from './search-question.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [SearchFilterPipe , CapitalizePipe],
  providers: [],
  exports: [SearchFilterPipe , CapitalizePipe]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

And import this shared module in whatever module you like and the pipe will be accessible from there without throwing any errors.

Comment: But in the posted code I'm using it in ONE module. And still, I have above error. If you can be so kind and look into my repository (only 30 files), and point me what's wrong, I will be very thankful